# Center Right-Floated Div on Window Resize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

I have 2 divs that I'm setting up to be next to each other in the desktop version of my site, and on the mobile / tablet version, I would like the right div to be on top and the left div to be underneath, with both of them centered inside their parent div. I have it set up like this:

```
<div id="right-top">right & top</div>
<div id="left-top">left & bottom</div>
```

And my CSS is like this:

```
#right-top {
  position: relative;
  float:right;
  width: 430px;
  height: 300px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

#left-top {
  position: relative;
  float:right;
  width: 430px;
  height: 300px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #666;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

They're floated right so that I can have the right div on top in smaller browser windows. How do I get them to be centered on smaller browsers, rather than aligned to the right side?

Comment: Do you have trouble using media queries or don't know how to use media queries or having trouble centering the divs in media queries?

Comment: I wasn't aware of @media queries, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it using mobile first design
That means defining how it will look first on small devices and progressively adding more rules for bigger screens

```
<div class="my-div" id="right-top">right & top</div>
<div class="my-div" id="left-top">left & bottom</div>
```

So we define the common rules (most of the stuff) between the 2 divs to a class (.my-div), the specifics to ids (#right-top, and #left-top)
And set a breakpoint in 860px (430px times 2 for each div), and only then, float the divs to the right.

```
.my-div{
  width: 430px;
  height: 300px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#right-top {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#left-top {
  background-color: #666;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 860px) {
    .my-div{
        float: right;
    }
}
```

You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mazLvmbe/)

Comment: This was super helpful, the idea of building it for small devices and then going up from there is the way to go I think. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JamesLikeness glad I could help! [This image](http://bradfrost.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/43-650x487.png) illustrates the reasons behind the mobile first ideology. Also remember to DRY (don't repeat yourself) if you need to write the same code for 2 things, it probably can be refactored and extracted into a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @media queries for responsive layout.

For eg:

```
@media (max-width: 769px){
    #right-top,#left-top{
        float: none;/*unset the floated div*/
    }
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4xt39rax/)